# jQuery check array for old value and push new value to array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying to push an object to an array and if the user changes a select option the object is pushed again but replacing the previous object with the same product_id.

Any help would be grateful, thanks.

```
function variationCheck(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < variationArray.length; i++) {
        if (variationArray[i].product_id === data.id) {
            var pushData = {'product_id':data.id,'variation_id':data.variation,'attribute_covers':data.covers,'attribute_extras':data.extras};
            variations.push(pushData);
            console.log(variations);
            for(var c = 0; c < variations.length; c++) {
                if(variations[c].product_id === data.id) {
                    variations.splice(c, 1);
                    var pushData = {'product_id':data.id,'variation_id':data.variation,'attribute_covers':data.covers,'attribute_extras':data.extras};
                    variations.push(pushData);
                    console.log(variations);
                }
            }
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: You can create object that mimics data in you form and change it without traversals.

e.g. like angular $scope.form

Answer (score 0):

Use Object instead of Array as data structure. As far, as I understand your `product_id` is unique, so it should be a key.

```
function variationCheck(data) {
    variationsObject[data.productId] = data;
};
```